# How to parameterize a part of string in a field of the request in karate

Tags: parameters, request, karate

I have a field in my request .I don't want to parameterize the entire field.

"user": "(KGS-ABCDE-GS\n-\n)\n",

The text ABCDE in the above field needs to be updated with a dynamic user always.Rest of the content need not be changed.The user field mentioned above is a part of my whole request.

I am trying to only make the particular test to fetch a value from a variable defined in the feature file.Could you please let me know how this can be done.
*def user = "HELLOUSER"
"user": "(KGS--GS\n-\n)\n",

Is there a need to have a javascript or some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

```
* def user = 'HELLOUSER'
* def temp = 'KGS-' + user + '-GS'
* def payload = { user: '#(temp)' }
```