# Embedded expression to frame a request with string in karate

Tags: parameter-passing, karate

I have trouble to parameterize into the below field.

```
   * def temp = 'KSG-' + user+ '-GS'
   * print temp 
   * def user = ('#(temp)'\n-C453/M-R/UVE S/J\n)\n
```

The actual field looks like `user: "(KSG-ABCDE-GS\n-C453/M-R/UVE S/J\n)\n"`

(full field value mentioned with `\n` also in quotes)

I get java script evaluation field when i provide temp value into this as mentioned above. Please correct me if I am providing temp value in wrong way in `* def user` part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [the docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions) I linked [in answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55337559)?

The below code should work. If you want to embed escaped line feeds, just use `\\n`:

```
* def user = 'foo'
* def temp = '(KSG-' + user + '-GS\n-C453/M-R/UVE S/J\n)\n'
* print temp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter.I was handling it incorrectly for the open braces.Your solution worked perfectly fine.Thanks again for your great support..